# Android Dev Set the height of a card view as dynamic

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Hi everyone I am developing an activity that displays the posts of a user and I will use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and LayoutInflater for the backend part. I'm trying to create the post layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/def2"

    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/crd_v"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
            app:cardCornerRadius="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_profilomain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"


                />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_text"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

            android:text="Nome Utente"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:visibility="visible"

            />




    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Titolo"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"


        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        >

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:srcCompat="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_like"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_marginTop="254dp"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"




            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="13dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/poplike"
            android:layout_marginTop="256dp"

            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut hendrerit lacus enim, nec placerat velit fringilla non. Nullam eleifend vestibulum bibendum. Etiam aliquam massa eget rutrum elementum. Vivamus sit amet enim molestie, aliquet quam et, mollis risus. Praesent lacinia congue purus, sed dignissim dui pellentesque et. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Mauris eget suscipit risus, in egestas ante. Mauris rhoncus quam vel velit volutpat, varius varius metus gravida. Aenean vel placerat turpis. Aenean id erat elementum, porttitor diam et, placerat lorem. Maecenas efficitur, sapien accumsan aliquam blandit, odio velit fermentum enim, eu egestas tortor mauris sit amet diam. Duis porta congue tellus, sed interdum ex suscipit id. Proin nec ex sem. Curabitur bibendum, magna vel dictum vulputate, odio nulla sollicitudin libero, posuere maximus libero nibh non ligula."
            android:layout_marginTop="268dp"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is the result of the previous code:

[image: result]

However as you can see the text (textview15) is cut from the height of the parent card view. I was wondering if there was a way (preferably from xml and not from java code) to match the height of the parent cardview with the height of the textview15. Anyone have an idea to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set wrap_content as height to parent card view.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
```